# How do I cast my 31st vote?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, votes

I just cast 30 votes, all on answers.  I then tried to vote on some questions, and was denied, with the message “Daily vote limit reached”.  I thought I was allowed an additional 10 votes on questions only, after I had cast my limit of 30 votes on answers.

Answer (score 3):

The additional 10 votes on questions comes into play if you've distributed your votes to questions and answers prior to the 30-vote limit, instead of *just* answers.

In a nutshell:

- Cast 30 votes to all answers: you get 30 votes
- Cast 30 votes to questions and answers([roughly 1 question vote for every 3 votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90734/133693)), you get 40.

Comment: This Q/A is a bit old... perhaps it's still handled the same. So, should @Scott have cast his (up to) 10 votes for questions first, then would he have been able to cast 30 votes for Answers? Or, would they need to be more evenly distributed? In any case, this sounds a bit "counter-intuitive" since after casting 30 votes: a mixture of 10-Questions, and 20-Answers, you would be allowed up to an add'l 10 votes for **Answers** (probably actually 10 add'l votes for Q's OR A's), which sounds opposite. Perhaps a better way to look at it: your FIRST 10 question votes don't count in the 30 vote limit.